# Access TextBox from ViewModel on IENumerable View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How do I access a textbox from my View Model? My page is returning a list of order numbers and I would like to have a search textbox at the top of the page. However, it appears that I can only access the textbox from a foreach statement.

**Simple View Model**

```
    public class ViewOrdersByCustomerIDViewModel
    {
       [Display(Name="Order Number / Order ID")]
       public int OrderID { get; set; }
       [DisplayName("Product Name")]
       public string ProductName { get; set; }
       [DisplayName("Order Date")]
       public DateTime ?OrderDate { get; set; }
       public string txtBoxOrderNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

I thought something like this would work but apparently is does not...

```
@model IEnumerable<something.something.ViewOrdersByCustomerIDViewModel>
@using (Html.BeginForm("OrderNumberSearch", "Order", FormMethod.Post))
{ 
    <strong>Enter Order Number / Order ID</strong>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.txtBoxOrderNumber)
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go" />
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

The purpose of the textbox is to filter/search the order numbers that are displayed. I only need one textbox for this and do not wish to loop through creating several search boxes. If my logic is off and there are better ways of accomplishing this, please let me know. I just thought it would be cleaner to have all properties within the model but that may not be the case.

Comment: As your model is `IEnumerable`, you need to iterate that and use TextBoxFor to get TextBoxes.

Comment: Why do you want it in Model? If you want to search, you can take it in your controller action and use it for searching.. Please update what you really want to do.

Comment: Not clear what you trying to do. Is the purpose of the form to get a filtered lists of orders that match the `OrderNumber`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes- thats what I'm trying to do

Comment: In that case you do not need `@model IEnumerable<ViewOrdersByCustomerIDViewModel>` (in fact you may not even need a model at all, just `<input type="text" name="SearchText" />` and post back to `public ActionResult OrderNumberSearch(string SearchText)` which then filters the results and returns a view (although ajax would probably be the best approach here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your ViewModels in following way -

```
public class OrdersByCustomerIDViewModel
{
    [Display(Name="Order Number / Order ID")]
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Product Name")]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Order Date")]
    public DateTime ?OrderDate { get; set; }
}

public class OrderSearchViewModel
{
    public List<OrdersByCustomerIDViewModel> Orders { get; set;}
    public string txtBoxOrderNumber { get; set; }
}
```

And in your View -

```
@model OrderSearchViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("OrderNumberSearch", "Order", FormMethod.Post))
{ 
    <strong>Enter Order Number / Order ID</strong>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.txtBoxOrderNumber)
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go" />
}

<!-- Here use the list to display results -->
 foreach(var item in Model.Orders)
 {
    @Html.LabelFor(m => item.ProductName)    
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. This works! Of course I had to change the controller but it works well.